# Meteor Update to 1.0.4.2 App Broken, Iron Router not working

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I just updated to 1.0.4.2 now my routes are not being run. Loading my app gives me an Iron Router splash page that says this

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Home', {
    data: function () { return Items.findOne({_id: this.params._id}); }
  });
});
```

UPDATE: It wasn't Meteor, it was this package `https://github.com/grigio/meteor-babel`. They removed the `.jsx` extension.

Comment: Could you show us your routes? Do you have any error?

Comment: Figured it out, it was `https://github.com/grigio/meteor-babel`. They removed `.jsx` extension.